# Can I declare a web API endpoint that accepts any arguments and lets me check them myself?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, routes, query-string

I am working on an ASP.NET-based .NET 4.6.1 web application. Our web API controllers make heavy use of the `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` attributes; routing is done by means of the `[Route]` attribute.

I understand that, if several methods have the same route, ASP.NET will distinguish them by their parameter names (and number).

Now, on one of my controllers, I would like to offer one method (whose route, or at least route + HTTP verb combination, is unique) that will accept any arguments in its query string. Preferrably, I would like to get the parsed query string as a list of key/value pairs, but if I have to parse the query string myself, that would also do.

**How can I achieve this while staying true to our general code structure (i.e. relying on `[Route]` for routing etc.)?**

I have found a couple of possible solutions, but somehow, something is always missing or at least, my findings are inconclusive due to a lack of documentation. For instance:

- I know I can probably access the full query string via the `HttpContext`, but that doesn't solve the routing issue that ASP.NET must map requests with arbitrary parameters to my method first.
- I have found some hints about model binders, but from when I implemented model binders a few months back, it seemed that they could only always process one argument at a time rather than all from the whole query string. (Or maybe I'm mistaken about that and got lost in the maze of supplied objects?)
- I have tried to use `DictionaryModelBinder<string, string>`, but all I'm getting from that one is an empty `Dictionary<string, string>`.

EDIT: As an example, I would like my endpoint (let's call it `call`) to react to any of the following:

```
.../call
.../call?a=5&b=20&c=800
.../call?a=foo&z=bar
```

**Brief rationale:** The method is on an abstract base class for my actual controllers. The information which URL parameters will actually be accepted by each individual controller can easily be extracted from runtime data/reflection, so I can return status 404 myself if the parameters received do not fit. What I do *not* want to do is implement the method individually for every single controller - even though that would let me specify different parameters on each controller, it would create an inconvenient redundancy.

EDIT2: Here's a shortened version of what the controllers look like:

The base class:

```
public abstract class ControllerBase<T, TKey> : ApiControllerBase
{
    [Route("call")]
    [HttpGet]
    public T Call([FromUri(Name = "")] TKey key)
    {
        // retrieve T from database based on key (for instance)
    }
}
```

And an actual controller:

```
public class Thing
{}

public class ThingKey
{
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[RoutePrefix("api/thing")]
public class ThingController : ControllerBase<Thing, ThingKey>
{}
```

And another controller:

```
public class Stuff
{}

public class StuffKey
{
    public int Scope { get; set; }
    public int Group { get; set; }
    public int UniqueKey { get; set; }
}

[RoutePrefix("api/stuff")]
public class StuffController : ControllerBase<Stuff, StuffKey>
{}
```

As is visible here, my `call` endpoint currently still maps the parameters from its URL query string to the properties of controller-specific objects. I would like to do away with the necessity of providing a separate key class for each controller and rather receive the arguments to `call` in a dictionary or similar.

Comment: Do you mind pasting your controller code? Did you have something like Call([FromQuery] queryParam)? Are you using .Net Core? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#binding-source-parameter-inference

Comment: @ZeinSleiman: I have updated the question to contain some example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accept a dictionary as below:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/call")]
public void SomeMethod(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    Dictionary<string,string> requestData= request.Content.ReadAsAsync<Dictionary<string,string>>().Result;
}
```

You can then read the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this when I'm at work again. Just for clarification, though: Isn't `Content` the request body? I need the arguments to be passed via the URL.

Comment: Turns out this is actually the correct solution: If a method with an `HttpRequestMessage` parameter exists on a route, it will apparently catch all the requests that do not match any of the other method signatures on the same route. I'm using the [`GetQueryNameValuePairs` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/mt174875(v%3Dvs.118)) to extract the parameters from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on custom model binder, you can use **`HttpRequestMessage`** as parameter in action method:

```
[Route("call")]
public IHttpActionResult SomeMethod(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(ParseQueryStringToDictionary(request));

    // some code here
}
```

Then you'll need to parse querystring to **`Dictionary<string, string>`** using **`ParseQueryStringToDictionary`** method:

```
private IDictionary<string, string> ParseQueryStringToDictionary(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var queryString = string.Join(string.Empty, request.RequestUri.ToString().Split('?').Skip(1));
    var queryStringValues = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
    return queryStringValues.Cast<string>().ToDictionary(x => x, x => queryStringValues[x]);
}
```

And call it: **`.../call?a=5&b=20&c=800`**

Comment: [Shan Nautiyal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58638963/1430156) was first, so I accepted that one, but upvoted yours.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Fair enough.